# Updating an autocompletion in TeXnicCenter

Tags: floats, texniccenter, auto-completion

I am trying to update the `figure` autocomplete in TeXnicCenter (TXC) to suit how I use `figure`s.

I believe I need to alter the Tex.xml file in `C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\Packages` and then restart TXC.

I have changed the `figure` entry to

```xml
<lxEnvironment name="figure" 
parameters="1" 
desc="Provides a figure environment for pstool"
icon="format.bmp"
index="9"
expafter="}%&#xA;\centering%&#xA;\psfragfig[width=0.8\textwidth]{test_chapter/test1_matlabfrag_20130917T1147_W3H1b}%&#xA;\caption{qwe2}%%&#xA;\label{fig:f1}%%&#xA;%&#xA;\end{figure}"
expbefore="\begin{f"/>
```

Strangely, in the application the autocomplete for figure still behaves as it did before I made this alteration. I don't know where TXC is getting the data now.

Any suggestions on what I need to do to change autocomplete?

My current work around is to add a text module in the insert menu. The only problem is this is a menu click rather than an autocomplete.

Comment: It seems that I needed to also restart my machine for the changes to take effect. I now have the above alteration working as expected.

Comment: Question can be considered too localized?

Comment: I think most standard windows 7 installs will find this is the typical behaviour. I'd be interested to know.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be solved by restarting the program.